# iOS 5 UIWebview not playing video?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a UIWebView within my application that is playing video correctly in iOS 4 but not playing in iOS 5. These are my video link.

1) `http://myserverpath/mov015.3gp`

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.selectedVideoUrl];
    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:req];
```

I also tried this but it also not worked.

```
    player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
    [[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];
    [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
    [player play];
```

Please help me.

Comment: Does that video play fine when accessed from Mobile-Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.3gp extension file is not supported by ios 5 web view. I have created another video with .mov extension and that works.